# WiFi keeps getting disconnected when I turn off screen?

Tags: settings, wifi, 7.x

I have a Lumia 610, running on WP 7.8

For some reason, whenever I turn off the screen, my WiFi keeps getting disconnected. This isn't in the settings. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is intentional, to save battery, and cannot be configured to behave differently on Windows Phone 7.x. As soon as you turn the screen back on, it should attempt to reconnect to known WiFi connections, and carry on using that.

It *shouldn't* affect any apps, as these also get suspended automatically, when the screen turns off, unless they request permission to run "under the lock screen" - which shows up in the Store when you install the app.

Comment: Apps which run under the lock screen, if they are accessing the network, may cause the WiFi to stay alive. This is probably what you want in that case. If the app closes its network connections, though (it may only do the keep-alive at all for stateful connections, not sure) then the WiFi will turn off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an app like: Keep Alive Wifi: http://windowsphonehacker.com/articles/experimental_keep_alive_for_wifi-08-10-12

I am not sure if you needed a rooted/unlocked phone for that, but I use(d) the app and it worked pretty good :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the below feature in 7.8 version. In version 8, its available.
Anyhow, you can check it.
1. Settings -> Wi-Fi -> Advanced -> Enable the check box "Keep Wi-Fi on when the screen times out".

Comment: There is no advanced option under wifi. Thanks